# Spring 3 MVC : Cleanest way to retrieve dynamic information in the header and footer if they are includes

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am looking for the cleanest way to retrieve and display information in my headers and footers. They are `.jspf` includes inside my `.jsp` files.

I know I could just boilerplate copy and paste `ModelMap.addAttribute` in every one of my controllers but that sounds like a terrible solution. I also do not want to use a session attribute if I can help it.

I was thinking that I could create a "Master Controller" class that all my other controller classes could extend from but, I am very interested in doing it the correct and most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `HandlerInterceptor` interface.  In the `postHandle` method, add the boilerplate to the `ModelMap`.  It will be there on every Handler call, automatically.